# Angular is not defined, reference error?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Installed latest angular to my project using

```
npm install angular@1.5.0-beta.2
```

Next, I added this anonymous function to my **app.js**:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('TimeWaste', []);
}());
```

Also I am using this in my **server.js** to give reference to my `node_modules`.

```
 app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules"));
```

Then I added reference to my project using:

```
<script scr="node_modules/angular/angular.js">
</script>
```

I am getting error on **app.js** file, it shows that angular is not defined.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @
>   app.js:2(anonymous function) @ app.js:3

Some help ?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 on angular.js? Can you post your app.js? Have you tried my answer? In which folder is your index file?

Comment: I posted my app.js in my post, already. Yes. Tried your answer and i did not solve my problem. Some other advice how to get this fixed ?

Comment: In which folder is your index file that is importing angular with the <script> tag? Let's try to isolate the problem, try to use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js this address to your <script>.

Comment: APP > index.html;
APP > app/app.js;
APP > node_modules/angular;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace your refrence

```
<script scr="node_modules/angular/angular.js">
```

use this.

```
    <script scr="angular/angular.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules"));
```

This will make `node_modules` a public folder.

So, you just need to use

```
<script scr="angular/angular.js">
</script>
```

to import Angular. ;)

Comment: It works when i put Angular CDN as reference. Any idea why with installed package and referencing it, it does not work ?